# LaTeX: Adding an Enumerate environment to a Tabular environment

Tags: latex

I am trying to add an ordered list (`enumerate`) to a table (`tabular`) in `LaTeX` with the following:

```
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  Event Flow & 
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item This is item 1
   \item This is item 2
   \end{enumerate}
  \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's
>   wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
>   Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.34    \item T
>            his is item 1 ?
> ```

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem exactly?

Because when I put the `enumerate` environment outside of the `tabular` environment, it works; so guess I am currently missing something with my example of the table.

Comment: You should probably only post a question like this to *one* of Stack Overflow and Super User (compare to http://superuser.com/questions/93498/latex-adding-an-enumerate-environment-to-a-tabular-environment ). Personally, I suspect that you will get a faster answer here.

Comment: Yes, you are very correct and I completely agree with you.  The reason I chose to ask it on superuser is because I thought it would be closed here;  I will now remove the question from superuser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  Event Flow & 
  \begin{minipage}{5in}
    \vskip 4pt
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item This is item 1
   \item This is item 2
   \end{enumerate}
   \vskip 4pt
 \end{minipage}
 \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm guessing the trouble is that the enumerate environment needs to be in vertical mode: you could experiment with a \vbox.

Comment: +1 Excellent, works now.  Thanks!  By any chance, do you know I can then vertical-align the content ('Event Flow') of the first cell?  Because it currently is center vertically-aligned.

Comment: There's no way to specify vertical alignment in tabulars (they're based on tex's \halign), so I guess the easiest is to put that in a parbox or minipage as well, and mess about with vskips there as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5cm}|}
  \hline
  Event Flow & 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is item 1
      \item This is item 2
    \end{enumerate} \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In other words, you can avoid the need for a `minipage` by simply creating a paragraph type column (which has a specified width). This compiles to

[image: table with enumerate]